# How to fix MySQL query not to return nulls

Tags: mysql

Here is my query,

```
SELECT
    p.pcode,
    p.productName,
    s.pcode,
    MAX(s.in_stock) AS opening_stock,
    SUM(s.soldQty) AS sold_qty,
    MIN(s.remaining_qty) AS closing_stock,
    s.date_created,
    g.pcode,
    g.qty,
    g.received_qty,
    g.received_on
FROM tbl_products p
LEFT JOIN tbl_sold_items s
    ON p.pcode = s.pcode
LEFT JOIN tbl_shop_gr_items g
    ON p.pcode = g.pcode
WHERE
    (s.date_created = '2019-09-27') AND
    (g.received_on = '2019-09-27')
GROUP BY p.pcode
```

[stock_report_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6T2T.png)

When the above query is executed it return null values when one of the selected table doesn't have the item id for that particular day. I want it to show a list of all the items(products) available even though the item has not been sold or received so that in those instances it should show zero (0)

Comment: Coalesce, ifnull ?

Comment: Note: Opening and closing stock comes from "tbl_sold_items" this table records a list of items sold for a particular sale. so each time an item has been sold i record its current stock(in_stock) before it has been sold and stock after a sale(remaining_qty)

Comment: That's a dubious group by since it does not contain non-aggregated columns , you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html particularly the bits about functional dependency and non determinency

Comment: Am using MySQL 5.6.17 which does support "IFNULL"

Comment: When i tried to use "COALESCE" still no results are shown

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use ISNULL to show zero value if NULL

```
SELECT 
    p.pcode, 
    p.productName, 
    s.pcode, 
    ISNULL(MAX(s.in_stock),0) AS opening_stock, 
    ISNULL(SUM(s.soldQty),0) AS sold_qty, 
    ISNULL(MIN(s.remaining_qty),0) AS closing_stock, 
    s.date_created,
    g.pcode, 
    g.qty, 
    g.received_qty, 
    g.received_on 
FROM tbl_products p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sold_items s ON p.pcode = s.pcode 
LEFT JOIN tbl_shop_gr_items g ON p.pcode = g.pcode 
WHERE(s.date_created = '2019-09-27') AND (g.received_on = '2019-09-27') 
GROUP BY p.pcode
```

Comment: ifnull in mysql not isnull https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Am using MySQL 5.6.17 which does support "IFNULL"

Comment: I have figured out the solution but before solving it am having a problem with this query 'SELECT p.pcode, p.productName,SUM(s.soldQty),g.pcode,SUM(g.received_qty) FROM tbl_products p LEFT JOIN tbl_sold_items s ON p.pcode = s.pcode LEFT JOIN tbl_shop_gr_items g ON p.pcode = g.pcode GROUP BY p.pcode'
it is doubling the results for instance, SUM(s.soldQty) should produce 3 but shows 6 and SUM(g.received_qty) gives 450 instead of 150. What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
p.pcode,
p.productName,
CASE
        WHEN gr_rows IS NULL AND sl_rows IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN gr_rows > 0 AND sl_rows IS NULL THEN received_stock
        WHEN gr_rows > 0 AND sl_rows > 0 THEN opening_stock
        ELSE 0
    END AS op_stock,
    IFNULL(received_stock, 0),IFNULL(sold_stock, 0)
FROM tbl_products p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(r.ID) AS gr_rows,r.pcode,r.received_on,SUM(r.received_qty) AS received_stock
    FROM tbl_shop_gr_items r
    WHERE r.received_on = '2019-10-03'
    GROUP BY r.pcode
)AS r ON p.pcode = r.pcode
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(s.ID) AS sl_rows,s.pcode,s.date_created,SUM(s.soldQty) AS sold_stock
    FROM tbl_sold_items s
    WHERE s.date_created = '2019-10-03'
    GROUP BY s.pcode
)AS s ON p.pcode = s.pcode
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.ID,t.pcode,t.date_created,t.remaining_qty AS opening_stock
    FROM tbl_sold_items t
    WHERE t.date_created > '2019-10-03'
    GROUP BY t.pcode ORDER BY t.ID
)AS t ON p.pcode = t.pcode
```

The above code has solved my issue